# Multiple users accessing the records from the DynamoDB concurrently

Tags: javascript, concurrency, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a problem with multiple users accessing DynamoDB at the same time, the users are getting duplicate sets of data across them. I tried creating a lock field in the table and setting it to true when I'm fetching the data, I'm getting 25 records and setting the lock status as True for all, but at the same time when other users access the list, he's getting duplicate records. I need to create a list of 25 records for users who can review that and update. I wanted to get unique records for all users. I know in the update condition we can have a check and prevent the overriding of the data update, but I wanted to eliminate in the fetch itself.  Any help is appreciated.

The application is built using ReactJS, so I need the solution in Javascript. I know there is a java implementation for the Dynamodb lock client with the lock table, I think the time taken for creating the lock for the 25 records and the fetch is varying resulting in the duplicate records fetched. A better approach to solving the problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it 25 separate lists or 25 items that make up a list?

Comment: 25 items make up a list